# Accessing a git_odb_writepack field in libgit2 gives error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

Tags: c, libgit2

I'm using libgit2 and I want to write a pack file to an odb created with `git_repository_odb`. So I call `git_odb_write_pack` and initialize a `*git_odb_writepack`. Then when I attempt to access a field of the writepack struct, I get a compiler error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type". Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <git2.h>

void check_error(int code, char *action) {
    if (code) {
        printf("Error %d, %s\n", code, action);
        exit(1);
    }
}

static int my_git_transfer_progress_callback(const git_transfer_progress *stats, void *payload) {
    printf("Got transfer callback\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int error;

    const char *repo_path = "/path/to/repo";
    git_repository *repo = NULL;
    error = git_repository_open(&repo, repo_path);
    check_error(error, "opening repo");

    git_odb *odb = NULL;
    error = git_repository_odb(&odb, repo);
    check_error(error, "initializing odb");

    git_odb_writepack *writepack = NULL;
    char *payload = "here's my payload";
    error = git_odb_write_pack(&writepack, odb, my_git_transfer_progress_callback, payload);
    check_error(error, "opening pack writing stream");

    printf("Address: %u\n", writepack->backend);  // <-- Line generating the error.

    return 0;
}
```

Then I compile and get the error:

> ```
> $ gcc -lgit2 writepack_error.c && LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./a.out
> writepack_error.c: In function 'main':
> writepack_error.c:33: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
> ```

I'm using libgit2 version 0.21.0. I'm new to C and libgit2 so I may be doing something silly. My understanding is this "dereferencing" error means I failed to define or include a struct or typedef. However I thought libgit2 only requires one include, `#include <git2.h>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal usage is covered by `git2.h`. Some functionality is kept under the `sys/` directory to indicate that it's considered more advanced usage.

This in particular looks like it might be a bug since `git2.h` does not include `git2/odb_backend.h`. For now you can simply include it manually.

Comment: Yep, I think that's it, thanks. I added `#include <git2/odb_backend.h>` and my example code worked. I also filed https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/2551